# How to update the values for import functionality in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a import.rb file which maps different headers and stores it to database through csv/xls upload.
In that there are some fields which are new fields building directly.
For example, name and website are stored directly in companies table but  alt_email and alt_email2 are stored in email table with type customers.
(Number of records stored at a time).
Here company has_many emails.

This is my rb file:

```
def import
  name = fetch_value(row, "Customer Name", :string)
  website = fetch_value(row, "Website", :string)
  cust_alt_email = fetch_value(row, "Customer Alternate Email1", :string)
  cust_alt_email2 = fetch_value(row, "Customer Alternate Email2", :string)
  customer_name = fetch_value(row, "Customer Name", :string)
  company = customer_name ? customer_name.strip.chomp.squeeze(" ") : ""
  if company.present?
    customer = Company.new
    customer.name = company
    customer.website = website

    if cust_alt_email.present?
      customer.emails.build(email: cust_alt_email)
    end
    if cust_alt_email2.present?
      customer.emails.build(email: cust_alt_email2)
    end

  else
    customer = Company.find_by_id(customer_name_to_id[company.downcase])
    if customer
      customer.name = company
      customer.website = website
    end    
  end    
end
```

Insert values is working fine. Like build for create, how to update the values or replace the current values with old ones?
Please help me.

Comment: Well you have `if company.present?` then in the else you try and use company which is going to set it presumably to nil.  Where does company come from?  Is it an association?  Why do you have local variables called `customer` that are instances of `Company` then set a company variable on them?

Comment: @j-dexx - I edited my question.

Comment: So what is the problem?  The emails?  You can either delete all that companies emails and create new ones or determine which are still in from the import, delete the others and create any new ones.

Comment: whenever I update I want to replace old ones with the new. Either delete and create as you said.